# Should the "dual" tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

This [dual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dual) tag appears to be a random assortment of questions involving dual booting, dual SIM cards, dual monitors, SQL, and so on, none of which appears to require the tag to establish the question. In addition, the only place that `dual` is actually used properly would be in SQL questions about a `dual` table of some sort. It appears to meet all the criteria for a burninate request if the SQL questions are ignored, and in general, I don't think people tag "index" on questions about a SQL index either.

Comment: It's useless if it's questions are that diverse. Burninate it.

Comment: Even if someone legitimately asked about the `Dual` table, it still isn't really useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He's dead, Jim. :)

---

Yea, that tag is pretty useless.  No wiki, no followers, only 96 questions, and, as you demonstrated in your question, it can be used to mean too many different things.

As for dual tables, we could always make a  more specific [dual-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dual-tables) tag if we *must* have a tag for that.  But that is a different story.

I say we burninate [dual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dual).  If there are no objections, I'm gonna start clearing it from the site (all help is welcome).